# How to fit data with non linear function and plot data and fit with ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

A measurement shows a signal that is formed like a square root function with offset and a factor. How can I find the coefficients and plot the raw data and the fitted curve in one plot?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(nlmrt)  # may be this will help later..?

# generate simulated measurement data

time <- seq(-10,20,0.2)

signal <- sqrt(time + 2) # generate sqrt signal; includes some NA
signal[is.na(signal)] <- 0 # set all NA to zero
signal <- signal + rnorm(length(time)) * 0.1  # add noise

df <- data.frame(x=time, y=signal)

# find coefficiants for y ~ b * sqrt(x - a)
# no idea how...

# plot raw data and fitted curve in one ggplot diagram

ggplot()+
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

[image]

Comment: Just a hint, you probably want to fit `y ~ b * sqrt(x - a)`, as opposed to `a + b*sqrt(c*x)`.

Comment: If you can't specify the cutoff point *a priori* (i.e. if it's a fitted parameter), you're probably going to have to fit this separately (it wouldn't fit into a linear model framework, and there are particularly tricky aspects to fitting cutoffs since the goodness-of-fit is flat over the intervals between data points).  If you can specify the cutoff then I think you can construct a dummy variable and do this ...

Comment: As first step I can define a constant for cutoff manually. Later I would like to find this automatic. But this might be topic of another question then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you know where the cutpoint is and that the value before the cutpoint is zero:

```
sfun <- function(x,brk,a=1) {
    ifelse(x<brk,0,suppressWarnings(a*sqrt(x-brk)))
}
```

(`suppressWarnings()` is there because `ifelse` evaluates both the *if* and the *else* cases for all values of `x`, and we don't want warnings about taking the square root of negative numbers)

Test (not shown):

```
curve(sfun(x,1,1),from=0,to=10) ## test (not shown)
```

Simulate some data:

```
x <- seq(0,10,length=101)
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(length(x),sfun(x,1,1),sd=0.25)
DF <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Since all we need to figure out is how the square root function is scaled, we can do this with a regression through the origin (take out the `-1` if you want to allow the value below the cutpoint to be non-zero):

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(DF,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",
                formula=y~sfun(x,brk=1)-1)
ggsave("truncsqrt.png")
```

[image]

Comment: oops, I didn't even notice that you'd provided your own simulation code. Anyone who wants can feel free to edit in the OP's example.

Comment: Perfect! How is the width of the grey band defined? And can I even get the coefficients as numbers?

Comment: the grey band is the 95% confidence interval.  If you want the coefficients, just do `lm(y~sfun(x,brk=1)-1,data=DF)`